# Count if a particular element is within a given range?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a vector made up of lists of length 10. 
I have two other vectors storing their lower and upper quantiles. 
Is there a way to extract the data between the quantile for each list of 10?

Basically I am looking to see how many of these have a specific number.

sims is the vector with the data

so far I have tried to use the %in% (note- sims is the vector with lists))

```
 for (i in 1:100){
  a <- 80.0  %in% sims[[i]]
 }
```

I was going to count how many of these are true and then count them however, this only returns false and also doesn't guarantee if it is in the range.

Is there an easier way than sorting each list by extracting relevant data then checking if it is has the value?

Comment: Please include minimal sample data in a reproducible and copy&paste-able format using e.g. `dput`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide a sample dataset here is a reproducible example based on some sample data I generate

```
set.seed(2018)
lst <- replicate(4, sample(10), simplify = FALSE)
qrt <- lapply(lst, quantile, probs = c(0.25, 0.75))
```

Here I've generated the 25% and 75% quantiles for every `vector` in `list`; the result is a `list` with as many elements as `list`.

We can now use `Map` to select only those entries from the `list` elements that fall within the quantile range

```
Map(function(x, y) x[x >= y[1] & x <= y[2]], lst, qrt)
#[[1]]
#[1] 4 5 7 6
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 4 6 5 7
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 6 5 4 7
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 4 7 6 5
```

To count the number of elements within the quantile range

```
Map(function(x, y) sum(x >= y[1] & x <= y[2]), lst, qrt)
#[[1]]
#[1] 4
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 4
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 4
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 4
```